# Finding the inverse of a matrix in R using the Schulz generalized method

Tags: r, algorithm, math, matrix

I have to get the inverse of a matrix using the Schulz generalized
inversion algorithm. And then I have to output in a list the number of iterations the code ran for, the value of δk at the final iteration, the inverse of the matrix. The output should be:

```
A = matrix(c(2,1,1,7,4,3,1,-1,0),nrow=3,ncol=3)
    my.inverse(A)[[1]]
    ## [1] 31
    my.inverse(A)[[2]]
    ## [1] 1.44329e-15
    my.inverse(A)[[3]]
    ## [,1] [,2] [,3]
    ## [1,] -1.5 -1.5 5.5
    ## [2,] 0.5 0.5 -1.5
    ## [3,] 0.5 -0.5 -0.5
```

I get `NAN` values, and don't know what could be wrong.

This is my code so far

```
schulz_inverse <- function(M, del = 1e-6, max_iter = 1000) {
  # Compute value of a
  a <- runif(1, 0, 2 * norm(M %*% t(M), "1"))
  
  # Initialize variables
  n <- nrow(M)
  Xk <- diag(n)
  
  # Iterate Schulz algorithm until convergence or max iterations reached
  for (k in 1:max_iter) {
    # Compute Ek
    Xk <- 2 * Xk - Xk %*% M %*% Xk
    
    # Compute delta_k
    delta_k <- sum(abs(Xk - Xk %*% M %*% Xk))
    
    # Check convergence
    if (delta_k < del) {
      break
    }
  }
  
  # Return results as a list
  list(iterations = k, delta_k = delta_k, inverse = Xk)
}
```

Answer (score 3):

First of all, it would be appreciated if you can provide some reference about the generalized Schulz algorithm for your implementation, since there might be some improved versions or variations.

---

I think you have several problems in your code:

1. Should initialize `Xk` with a scalar that is sufficiently small (mine is using the inverse of max eigen value, for example). ***This is to ensure the iteration process converges***.
2. Should update `2 * Xk - Xk %*% M %*% Xk` to an intermediate variable, e.g., `Xkk`, instead of `Xk`
3. Should compare `Xkk` (not `Xk`) with `Xk %*% M %*% Xk`
4. Replace `Xk` by `Xkk` if `delta_k` condition is not met

```
schulz_inverse <- function(M, del = 1e-6) {
    # Initialize variables
    Xk <- M / (2 * norm(M, "2"))
    k <- 0
    # Iterate Schulz algorithm until convergence or max iterations reached
    repeat {
        # Compute Ek
        Xkk <- 2 * Xk - Xk %*% M %*% Xk
        # Compute delta_k
        delta_k <- sum(abs(Xkk - Xk %*% M %*% Xk))
        # Check convergence
        if (delta_k < del) {
            break
        } else {
            k <- k + 1
            Xk <- Xkk
        }
    }
    # Return results as a list
    list(iterations = k, delta_k = delta_k, inverse = Xk)
}
```

## Output

```
A <- matrix(c(2, 1, 1, 7, 4, 3, 1, -1, 0), nrow = 3, ncol = 3)

> schulz_inverse(A)
$iterations
[1] 12

$delta_k
[1] 2.701173e-13

$inverse
     [,1] [,2] [,3]
[1,] -1.5 -1.5  5.5
[2,]  0.5  0.5 -1.5
[3,]  0.5 -0.5 -0.5
```

Answer (score 1):

Your Xk values are too close to R's limits for single numbers. For example `Xk[1,1] =  -8.072787e+162` in iteration k=8. So, when you multiply `Xk` by itself the values go beyond the acceptable bounds and R calls it `Inf` for infinite.

Subsequently, you subtract an `Inf` from another as part of the matrix multiplication which outputs `NaN` since `Inf-Inf`is not defined in math.

I do not know schulz_inverse's math but it seems weird that it would generate such large numbers. I'd double-check that the code represents the actual algorithm.